# Accessing an Object from other Method

Tags: oracle-adf

I am trying to access view objects from Java method.

These objects are not viewed in my page. so I cant use getter and setter methods.

Is there a way I can retrieve data from these view objects using SQL queries?

Answer (score 1):

Accessing view objects from the view layer is not a good practice.How ever if the required view object which you need to access is added to application module then you can access that from the model layer
methods(VOImpl and VORowImpl) pertaining to the view object used in the jsf page.

Just access the app module first and then get the required ViewObject and you can perform the required query on that.

Comment: I don't have a code pertaining to this case.you can go through http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/b31974/bcquerying.htm http://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/downloads/4828EN_Appendix_More_on_ADF_Business_Components_and_Fusion_Page_Runtime.pdf

Comment: im using this code:      public void addrow()
     {
                 ViewObjectImpl vo=getKey2();
                    Row r=vo.createRow();
                      r.setAttribute("Id", "55");
                      r.setAttribute("Name", "testKey");
                       r.setAttribute("Md_Table_Id", "1");
                      r.setAttribute("Type", "P");
           vo.insertRow(r);
           this.getDBTransaction().commit();
               
         } but i keep getting a null pointer exception when the code reach Row r=vo.CreateRow(); !!

Comment: is `getKey2()` correct method for accessing the view object.I think your method is returning null and so calling createRow() on null object is returning null pointer exception

Comment: yes it was returning null object. solved it by getting the current appmodule instance with this code:         ApplicationModule am= Configuration.createRootApplicationModule("com.capella.primetdm.model.appModules.AppModule", "AppModuleLocal");
                     AppModuleImpl am2 = (AppModuleImpl)am; thanks